# How can I decrease both top and bottom outer spacing?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am working on a project and I am using `z-index` and `position: relative` to position 2 divs on top of each other. However I cannot use both `top` and `bottom` to make the proper outer spacing.
Is there some way to decrease the distance between the surounding elements without changing their spacing?

```css
.contactDetail {
  position: relative;
  top: 515px;
}

.picture {
  img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="row align-items-center">
    {% for detail in row.children.all() %}
    <div class="detailBox col-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="box">
        <p>{{ detail.text }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </header>
</div>
<div class="picture">
  <img src="{{ row.image.one().getUrl('contact_image') }}">
</div>
```

The image is supposed to go to the end of the page and be positioned under `detail.text`. By giving `top: 515px` to `.contactDetail` the outer space between it and the element above is too big. I also do not want to touch the other elements because they are used on multiple other places.

Comment: Does it really have to be relative positioned? Sounds like you could do with a parent/child div with padding on the parent or margin on the child.

Comment: Please do not just show a tiny snippet of CSS when asking this kind of question, but a proper [mre] of the issue. (Yes, we could _guess_ what the HTML you want to apply this to might look like - but we might also guess _wrong_; and even if we didn't - it is much more effective for you to provide the example when asking, rather than every single person reading the question having to create one on their own.)

Comment: You could do that parent child thing to make parent relative an child to absolute so then you can set top bottom parameters or padding margin that point you don't need the z-index

Comment: Please show a proper [mcve]. Emphasis on minimal. If you've got a problem styling your HTML then show us the HTML and not some code that would generate it if we have some data that could be fed into that code. I've converted the code you've provided into a live demo, as you can see: the code isn't very helpful.

Comment: @CBroe I included a bit more information that I hope it might be useful.

Comment: @NickyIchov Move the picture to outside top of the container and then wrap it in another div both image and container and give the style position relative to that wrapper and then both position absolute and use z-index this will solve the provblem

Comment: Not very useful, because it still contains templating tags - see how that snippet above renders? You should present the resulting HTML code.

Comment: @NickyIchov share a image show us how it looks and then tell what the way you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this way

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <header class="row align-items-center">
        {% for detail in row.children.all() %}
        <div class="detailBox col-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
          <div class="box">
            <p>{{ detail.text }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </header>
    </div>
    <div class="picture">
      <img src="{{ row.image.one().getUrl('contact_image') }}">
    </div>
  </div>
```

style

```
.wrapper {
position: relative;
}

.contactDetail {
    position: absoulte;
    top: 515px;
}

.picture {
      img {
        position: absoulte;
        z-index: 2;
        bottom: 150px;
      }
    }
```

put your style how ever you want

Comment: set wrapper height so that part you can mange your image and text however you want

Comment: I like the idea of parent and child divs and it might work. However, I will need to play around with it a bit.